# How to perform a load test on a triggered send

Tags: api, triggered-send, subscriber, test-setup, subscriber-key

I'm looking to perform a load test on a triggered send by pushing ~160k records through the trigger. For the test, we are planning on taking a block of live records and replacing the email address with an internal one so that the triggered email is not sent to a live subscriber.

I can't find any best practices around such a test and would like to confirm that how the test is outlined above will not result in a live subscriber receiving the test send if the subscriber is already part of 'All Subscribers' or the 'Triggered Send Managed List.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have any issues so long as you are 1000% sure that no production email addresses are going to be passed to the triggered send for deployment.

I think it would probably be prudent to triple check your test data as well as adding an exclusion script in the triggered send definition that prevents any emails deploying to subscribers whose email address doesn't match the format of your test data exactly (i.e. where emailaddress doesn't contain your company's domain or the test alias if you are using the gmail inbox hack).